# show posts from some category and sort by advance custom field

Tags: categories

i want code that show display some category and sort by acf field.

for example show all post from category 122,123,124 and sort all of them by acf (for example : lastname ). please write code for me.

my code is :

```
<?php

query_posts('cat=1,2&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=1');

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title (); ?></a>

<?php

endwhile; else:

endif;

//Reset Query

wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

please help me. thanks

Comment: Sort by which field?

Comment: ACF only adds the meta boxes and has nothing to do with displaying the results on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should stop using `query_posts()`. [As said in the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query.

You can find a more comprehensive explanation in [this answer by @Rast](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

For new loops, as you are doing in the description of your question, it is better to use [`WP_Query` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). With this class you can use the `cat` paramter to get posts from specific categories and combine `meta_key` (or `meta_query`) with `order` and `orderby` parameter to sort by a custom field. It doesn't if the custom field is created by ACF or by any other way, all you need is the key of the meta field.

```
$args = array (
    'cat'      => '122,123,124',
    // Change the_identifier_key_of_the_field with the identifier of your field
    'meta_key' => 'the_identifier_key_of_the_field',
    // Set order to ASC or DESC
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    // Use 'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num' for numeric meta fields
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while( $query->have_posts() ) {

         $query->the_post();

         ?>

         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title (); ?></a>

         <?php

    }

}

// Reset original post data after the secondary loop
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: thanks. i test it but dont work. :(

Comment: Have you change `'meta_key' => 'the_identifier_key_of_the_field'` with the identifier of your field? Have you change `'orderby'  => 'meta_value'` with `'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num'` if the field stores numeric values? This code is the way to sort by custom field using WP methods and it works for the rest of the world. So it must works also for you. Please, post the exact code you have tried and it is not working so we can test it. Also, when you say "it doesn't work" please explain why, "don't work" says nothing about the problem.

Comment: Also, the type of field you are using could be the problem. There are some fields types provided by ACF that don't support sorting in the way WP does; in that case you should ask to ACF plugin developers for a way to solve the problem. Can you tell use the field type you are using?

Comment: please help me. i put my code in blow,

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers.

my code is :

```
<?php 

$args = array (
'cat'      => '144,122,124,125,126',
'meta_key' => 'lastname',
// Set order to ASC or DESC
'order'    => 'DESC',
// User 'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num' for numeric meta fields
'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ) {

while( $query->have_posts() ) {

     $query->the_post();

     ?>
    <div class="nzr_gallery">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');?>
            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php

}

}

// Reset original post data after the secondary loop
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

i put this code in page-members.php and create a page in wordpress and put template to members. when i choose some categories, this code display Intersection posts of theme and dont show all of theme.

Comment: Please [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/197036/edit) to add this information. Don't use the answers to not answer. In the edition, try explain what do you mean with "this code display Intersection posts of theme and dont show all of theme"; I don't understand what you mean.